# Debounce a refresh button in VSCode extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So my issue is that I would like to wrap a refreshing function for the treeview in a debounce so the user wont be able to make a lot of calls by clicking too fast. What I have is this function:

```
  async refresh(isButton: boolean): Promise<void> {
...
    providersSingleton.load(loadedItems);
    MyTreeProvider.onDidChangeTreeDataEmitter.fire();
    ..
  }
```

The thing is refresh() button isn't called anywhere else accessible for me so I can't just wrap it in a _.debounce. How can I debounce say 20 clicks in a second?

Comment: If you can use RxJS, [`debounceTime`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounceTime) can do what you're describing. Debounce the click events, then do the work once the debounce condition has passed. [`debounce`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounce) is also an option.

Comment: set a timer at the first click, if timer is still not fired ignore next clicks, on timer fire clear the timer variable